# Filter list of records in controller displayed in an apex:pageBlockTable

Tags: apex, controller

My code is based on code shared by another stackexchange user. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26183938/visualforce-page-does-not-display-a-list-of-records-or-any-records-but-it-can-di

Where in the controller would you limit the query to certain types of records instead of the full list of records? A 'WHERE' statement in the queryString isn't allowed and doing 'IF' statements in the list above PageReference refresh() returns a count of 49 records in the list instead of 3. I can find the 3 records if I look through the list with the buttons, but the 3 records should ideally appear at the top of the list on the first page.

[image: No records visible but returning 49 records in the list when there should be 3.]

[image: Found 3 records by clicking next.]

This is the code I currently have for my controller:

```
public class VOActivityHomeListController {

public apexpages.standardsetcontroller con {get;set;}
public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;}
public Integer size{get; set;}
public VOActivity__c voas {get; set;}

public List<VOActivity__c> AllSearchActivities {
    get {
        if (con!= null)
            return (List<VOActivity__c>)con.getRecords();
        else
            return null;
    }
    set;
}

public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get{
        if(setCon == null) {
            size = 10;
            string queryString = 'SELECT Name, Activity__c, Clinical_Study__c, Scheduled_Date__c, Status__c, Current_User_Equals_Assigned_To__c FROM VOActivity__c ORDER BY Scheduled_Date__c ASC NULLS LAST';
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
            setCon.setPageSize(size);
            noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize();
        }
        return setCon;
    }
    set;
}

public List<VOActivity__c> getActivities() {
    List<VOActivity__c> activityList = new List<VOActivity__c>();
    for(VOActivity__c w : (List<VOActivity__c>)setCon.getRecords())
        if (w.Current_User_Equals_Assigned_To__c != 'FALSE') if (w.Status__c <> 'Submitted') {
            activityList.add(w);
        }
    return activityList;
}

// Table refresh
public PageReference refresh() {
    setCon = null;
    getActivities();
    setCon.setPageNumber(1);
    return null;
}

// Scroll through records button functions
public PageReference Search() {
    if (voas.Name != null) {
        con = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Name, Activity__c, Clinical_Study__c, Scheduled_Date__c, Status__c, Current_User_Equals_Assigned_To__c FROM VOActivity__c  VOActivity__c WHERE Name = :voas.Name]));  
        con.setPageSize(10);
    }
    else {
        con = null;
    }
    return null;
}

public Boolean hasNext {
    get {
        return setCon.getHasNext();
    }
    set;
}
public Boolean hasPrevious {
    get {
        return setCon.getHasPrevious();
    }
    set;
}

public Integer pageNumber {
    get {
        return setCon.getPageNumber();
    }
    set;
}

public void first() {
    setCon.first();
}

public void last() {
    setCon.last();
}

public void previous() {
    setCon.previous();
}

public void next() {
    setCon.next();
}

}
```

Comment: why do you think you can't use a where clause in the Database.getQueryLocator(queryString) ?

Comment: When I add a WHERE clause to.... string queryString = 'SELECT Name, Activity__c, Clinical_Study__c, Scheduled_Date__c, Status__c, Current_User_Equals_Assigned_To__c FROM VOActivity__c ORDER BY Scheduled_Date__c ASC NULLS LAST'; ... I get Error: VOActivityHomeListController Compile Error: expecting a semi-colon, found 'Submitted' at line 29 column 187

Comment: the WHERE has to be placed before the ORDER BY

Comment: @crop1645 Correct.  I've done ... string queryString = 'SELECT Name, Activity__c, Clinical_Study__c, Scheduled_Date__c, Status__c, Current_User_Equals_Assigned_To__c FROM VOActivity__c WHERE Status__c != 'Submitted' ORDER BY Scheduled_Date__c ASC NULLS LAST'; ... and get the error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: ah, you need to escape the quotes around the `'Submitted'` as in `status__c != \'Submitted\' order by ...`

Comment: @crop1645 Thank you! That solved it. I had never needed to do that before. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: great; usually one gets a compile error but in your case you did not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@crop1645 found the solution.  The formatting of the WHERE clause matters.

```
string queryString = ' ... FROM VOActivity__c 
                       WHERE Status__c != \'Submitted\' ORDER BY Scheduled_Date__c';
```

not

```
string queryString = ' ... FROM VOActivity__c 
     WHERE Status__c != 'Submitted' ORDER BY Scheduled_Date__c';
```

because of how string structuring.